# Nesting Aggregate Functions - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I want to make a SQL query which finds the catagory of awards for movies which has the highest average rating, so for a group of movies which have won a particular award, if they have a higher average rating than any other awards group of movies then it will be returned.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(AVG(m."Rating"))
FROM awards a, movies m
WHERE a."Title" = m."Title"
GROUP BY a."Award"
```

but it seems that aggregate functions cannot be nested. How can I call the max function on the average ratings for each catagory?

Answer (score 15):

If you are only interested in the value itself, the following should do it:

```
SELECT MAX(avg_rating)
FROM (
    SELECT AVG(m."Rating") as avg_rating
    FROM awards a, movies m
    WHERE a."Title" = m."Title"
    GROUP BY a."Award"
) t
```

Otherwise Adrian's solution is better.

Answer (score 9):

This will bring your desired result:

```
SELECT a."Award", AVG(m."Rating")
FROM awards a, movies m
WHERE a."Title" = m."Title"
GROUP BY a."Award"
ORDER by AVG(m."Rating") desc
LIMIT 1
```

This will allow you not only get the `MAX` value, but its corresponding `Award` info

Comment: @Julian I never said LIMIT is SQL standard. It solves OP issue because LIMIT is also available in PostGreSQL (not only MySQL!), which is OP's RDBMS.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this?

```
SELECT MAX(
   SELECT AVG(m."Rating")
   FROM awards a, movies m
   WHERE a."Title" = m."Title"
   GROUP BY a."Award"
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that has a syntax error "at or near SELECT". Not sure what that would be

Comment: @steve, Commenting the inner SELECT SQL with a set of braces would solve that error. The Braces force the executing of the SELECT Scalar query **before** the MAX() kicks in.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use windowed `MAX`:

```
SELECT MAX(AVG(m."Rating")) OVER()
FROM awards a -- proper JOIN syntax
JOIN movies m ON a."Title" = m."Title"     
GROUP BY a."Award"
LIMIT 1;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f9940ed6c4b2b831a7b5992eb79fb3c6)**