# postgres aggregate function calls may not be nested

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query:

```
    select sum(
        sum((Impressions / Count) * Volume) / sum(Volume)
    ) as frequency 
    from datatable;
```

however I cannot execute this in postgres because it uses nested aggregations. Is there another way to write this without using nested aggregations?

Comment: What do you think it means? Can you give some example data/results?

Comment: What do you think the outer sum() does? It seems that the term sum((Impressions / Count) * Volume) / sum(Volume) should be only one value so I don't know what the outer sum() could be doing.

Comment: Please define "this". What you display so far does not make sense. Start with the table definition (`\d tbl` in psql) and your version of Postgres. Add an explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nesting Aggregate Functions - SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141452/nesting-aggregate-functions-sql)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need to nest aggregation functions, you will need to use some form of subquery. I am using `product` column as an arbitrary choice for grouping column. I also renamed `Count` to `dcount`.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6607b/2)

Sample data:

```
create table sample (
  product varchar,
  dcount int,
  impressions int,
  volume int
);

insert into sample values ('a', 100, 10, 50);
insert into sample values ('a', 100, 20, 40);
insert into sample values ('b', 100, 30, 30);
insert into sample values ('b', 100, 40, 30);
insert into sample values ('c', 100, 50, 10);
insert into sample values ('c', 100, 60, 100);
```

Query:

```
select
  sum(frequency) as frequency
from 
  (
  select
    product,
    sum((impressions / dcount::numeric) * volume) / sum(volume) as frequency
  from 
    sample
  group by
    product
  ) x;
```

The point is that you cannot nest aggregate functions. If you need to aggregate aggregates then you need to use subquery.