# How to include three or more aggregators in a sql query?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table called `retail` which stores `items` and their `price` along with `date` of purchase. I want to find out **total monthly count of unique items sold**.

This is the sql query I tried

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as month, sum(count(distinct(items))) as net_result from retail group by month order by date;
```

But I get the following error

```
ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested
```

Now I searched for similar stackoverflow posts one of which is [postgres aggregate function calls may not be nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063370/postgres-aggregate-function-calls-may-not-be-nested) and but I am unable to replicate it to create the correct sql query.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it doesn't seem like you need to nest the aggregate functions, the count(distinct item) construction will give you a count of distinct items sold, like so:

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as month
 , count(distinct items) as unique_items_sold
 , count(items) as total_items_sold
from retail 
group by "month" 
order by "month" ;
```

If you had a column called item_count (say if there was row in the table for each item sold, but a sale might include, say, three widgets)

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as month
 , count(distinct items) as unique_items_sold
 , sum(item_count) as total_items_sold
from retail 
group by "month" 
order by "month" ;
```

Comment: Yep this is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries:

```
Select month, sum(citems) as net_result 
   from 
       (select 
           date_trunc('month', date) as month, 
           count(distinct(items)) as citems 
        from 
           retail 
        group by month 
        order by date
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am suspect your `group by` statement will throw an `Error` because your `month` column are condition column and you cannot put in the same level in your query so put your full expression instead.

```
select
  month,
  sum(disct_item) as net_results
from
  (select 
     date_trunc('month', date) as month, 
     count(distinct items) as disct_item
   from 
     retail 
   group by 
     date_trunc('month', date)
   order by 
     date) as tbl
group by
  month;
```

You cannot make nested aggregate so you wrap first `count` to `subquery` and after that in outer you make `sum` to do the operation.