# How to get the change number?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

How to increase value when `source` value is changed?
I have tried `rank`, `dense_rank`, `row_number` without success =(

```
id | src | how to get this?
--------
1  |  1  | 1
2  |  1  | 1
3  |  7  | 2
4  |  1  | 3
5  |  3  | 4
6  |  3  | 4
7  |  1  | 5
```

NOTICE: `src` is guaranteed to be in this order you see

is there simple way to do this?

Comment: Your query seems to be non-deterministic. It will depend on the order of the values returned by the query.

Comment: @dmg: Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by nesting two window functions - the first to get whether the `src` value changed from the previous row, the second to sum the number of changes. Unfortunately Postgres doesn't allow nesting window functions directly, but [you can work around that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24063370/1048572) with a subquery:

```
SELECT
  id,
  src,
  sum(incr) OVER (ORDER BY id)
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    (lag(src) OVER (ORDER BY id) IS DISTINCT FROM src)::int AS incr
  FROM example
) AS _;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d2aac92109e03f99ec72adfcf8724c0f))</sup>

Comment: Could it be possible to reach same without sub query?

Comment: @EugenKonkov You could of course write a custom aggregate function that does this, but I think the subquery is simpler