# SQL - aggregate functions cannot be nested error in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

table1

```
date_time               | make   | model | miles | reg_no | age_months
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | toyota | prius | 10200 | 1111   | 22
2016-09-28 20:06:03.001 | suzuki | sx4   | 10300 | 1122   | 12
2016-09-28 20:09:03.001 | suzuki | sx4   | 11200 | 1133   | 34
2016-09-28 20:10:03.001 | toyota | prius | 15200 | 1144   | 28
2017-05-28 20:11:03.001 | toyota | prius | 15500 | 1144   | 36
```

For data in table1 above I wanted do some aggregations on `miles` per `month` by model like mean, median, q1, q3, iqr etc.

The query I've is as follows, but it gives error: `aggregate functions cannot be nested` - what is the right way to go about this ?

```
select
    model
    , COUNT(DISTINCT reg_no) AS distinct_car_count
    , COUNT(*) AS records_count
    , ROUND(AVG(miles/age_months*1.0),2) AS miles_per_month_avg
    , ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (miles/age_months*1.0) ASC),2) AS miles_per_month_med
    , ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (miles/age_months*1.0) ASC),2) AS miles_per_month_q1
    , ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (miles/age_months*1.0) ASC),2) AS miles_per_month_q3
    , miles_per_month_q3 - miles_per_month_q1 as miles_per_month_iqr
    , sum(case when miles/age_months*1.0 <  (miles_per_month_q1 - 1.5*miles_per_month_iqr) then 1 else 0 end) as miles_per_month_num_records_outliers_lower_bound
    , sum(case when miles/age_months*1.0 >  (miles_per_month_q3 + 1.5*miles_per_month_iqr) then 1 else 0 end) as miles_per_month_records_outliers_upper_bound
    , ROUND(stddev_pop(miles/age_months*1.0),2) as miles_per_month_stddev

from table1 a
group by model;
```

Comment: You need to move the three lines starting with `, miles_per_month_q` into another level.

Comment: @dnoeth how do we do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nesting Aggregate Functions - SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141452/nesting-aggregate-functions-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues:

#1: You can't nest aggregates (as the error message clearly indicates), `miles_per_month_q1` is an aggregated column and yu try to use it in another aggregate `miles_per_month_num_records_outliers_lower_bound`.

#2: You try to reuse a column alias `miles_per_month_q1` within the calculation of `miles_per_month_iqr`, which is not allowed in Standard SQL.

For both cases you need to add another nesting level (i.e. Derived Table or Common Table Expression), in your case it's probably:

```
SELECT
    a.model
    , Count(DISTINCT reg_no) AS distinct_car_count
    , Count(*) AS records_count
    , Round(Avg(miles/age_months*1.0),2) AS miles_per_month_avg

    -- now you can use the aliases, but you have to add a dummy (it's always the same value for a given model) aggregation function like MIN or MAX    
    , Min(percentiles.miles_per_month_med)
    , Min(percentiles.miles_per_month_q1)
    , Min(percentiles.miles_per_month_q3)
    , Min(percentiles.miles_per_month_q3 - percentiles.miles_per_month_q1) AS miles_per_month_iqr

    -- now it's no more nested aggregation
    , Sum(CASE WHEN miles/age_months*1.0 <  (percentiles.miles_per_month_q1 - 1.5* (percentiles.miles_per_month_q3 - percentiles.miles_per_month_q1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS miles_per_month_num_records_outliers_lower_bound
    , Sum(CASE WHEN miles/age_months*1.0 >  (percentiles.miles_per_month_q3 + 1.5* (percentiles.miles_per_month_q3 - percentiles.miles_per_month_q1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS miles_per_month_records_outliers_upper_bound

    , Round(StdDev_Pop(miles/age_months*1.0),2) AS miles_per_month_stddev

FROM table1 a
JOIN
 ( -- calculate the nested aggregates first
   SELECT
       model
       , Round(Percentile_Cont(0.5) Within GROUP (ORDER BY (miles/age_months*1.0) ASC),2) AS miles_per_month_med
       , Round(Percentile_Cont(0.25) Within GROUP (ORDER BY (miles/age_months*1.0) ASC),2) AS miles_per_month_q1
       , Round(Percentile_Cont(0.75) Within GROUP (ORDER BY (miles/age_months*1.0) ASC),2) AS miles_per_month_q3
   FROM table1 a
   GROUP BY model
 ) AS percentiles
ON a.model = percentiles.model
GROUP BY a.model
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what is killing you:

```
, sum(case when miles/age_months*1.0 <  (miles_per_month_q1 - 1.5*miles_per_month_iqr) then 1 else 0 end) as miles_per_month_num_records_outliers_lower_bound
, sum(case when miles/age_months*1.0 >  (miles_per_month_q3 + 1.5*miles_per_month_iqr) then 1 else 0 end) as miles_per_month_records_outliers_upper_bound
```

You are using **SUM** on expressions (miles_per_month_q1,miles_per_month_q3) that are built upon another aggregative function  - **PERCENTILE_CONT**

```
,ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (miles/age_months*1.0) ASC),2) AS miles_per_month_q1
, ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (miles/age_months*1.0) ASC),2) AS miles_per_month_q3
```

Split the code to inner query with **PERCENTILE_CONT** wrraped by an outer query with **SUM**

---

### suggested solution

```
select
    model
    , COUNT(DISTINCT reg_no) AS distinct_car_count
    , COUNT(*) AS records_count
    , ROUND(AVG(miles/age_months*1.0),2) AS miles_per_month_avg
    , ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (miles/age_months*1.0) ASC),2) AS miles_per_month_med
    , min (miles_per_month_q1)  as miles_per_month_q1
    , min (miles_per_month_q3)  as miles_per_month_q3
    , miles_per_month_q3 - miles_per_month_q1 as miles_per_month_iqr
    , sum(case when miles/age_months*1.0 <  (miles_per_month_q1 - 1.5*(miles_per_month_q3 - miles_per_month_q1)) then 1 else 0 end) as miles_per_month_num_records_outliers_lower_bound
    , sum(case when miles/age_months*1.0 >  (miles_per_month_q3 + 1.5*(miles_per_month_q3 - miles_per_month_q1)) then 1 else 0 end) as miles_per_month_records_outliers_upper_bound
    , ROUND(stddev_pop(miles/age_months*1.0),2) as miles_per_month_stddev

from    (select       a.*
                    , ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (miles/age_months*1.0) ASC),2) over (partition by model) AS miles_per_month_q1
                    , ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (miles/age_months*1.0) ASC),2) over (partition by model) AS miles_per_month_q3

        from        table1 a
        ) a
        
group by  model
;
```

Comment: can you add some more direction for 'Split the code to inner query with PERCENTILE_CONT wrraped by an outer query with SUM'

Comment: @user3206440, please check the suggested solution I added to the answer